# Why is UITableViewSeparator visible through UIView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am adding a UIView (as a container view) to a UITableViewController. For some reason the UITableView separators are visible through the UIView. I am running iOS 7.

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.width, 50)];
container.opaque = YES;
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:224.0/255.0 green:224.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[self.view container];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in viewDidLoad of UITableViewController

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Unless you set the footer view UITableView draw separator lines below it as well. To eliminate them either you can set it as empty view as I did above or do

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
     // This will create a "invisible" footer
     return 0.01f;
 }
```

OR

set separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone